# Get maximum group by

Tags: excel, group-by, max

On Excel, I have a table like this between cells A1 and C15:

```
1 1 36
1 2 24
1 3 18

2 1 20
2 2 20
2 3 20

3 1 36
3 2 18
3 3 17

4 1 15
4 2 15
4 3 21
```

On my column D, I want to write:

- “T” if the C value is strictly the maximum group by column B
- “TE” if the C value is the maximum among others group by column B

In my exemple it must output the following result:

```
1 1 36 TE
1 2 24 T
1 3 18

2 1 20
2 2 20
2 3 20

3 1 36 TE
3 2 18
3 3 17

4 1 15
4 2 15
4 3 21 T
```

Do you know how I could do with Excel formulas?
Thanks.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how you define a group, is it based on column B values, for example, all 1s belong to the same group, all 2s to another group, and so on or is it based on a group delimited by an empty row?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in D1, and copy it down as far as you need:

```
=IFS(C1="","",
C1=MAX(C:C),"TE",
C1=MAXIFS(C:C,B:B,B1),"T",
TRUE,"")
```